# How to secure AnguageJS application against users calling AJAX methods when logged in?

Tags: angularjs, security

I am converting an application from PHP to PHP/AngularJS. In this application, users can log in and then do things to score points. In the AngularJS application when a player scores points, I increment his points with an AJAX call e.g. `/process.php?action=addPoints&userId=234&pointsToAdd=5`. I, of course, check to see if user `23` is currently logged in before I add his points, so that points can't be changed by a person who is not logged in.

However, I also don't want a technically savvy person to be able to log in and then upgrade his own score e.g. by sending CURL calls to the `process.php` file.

What is the standard way to prevent this? Can I just check e.g. the `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]` and make sure that the call is coming from site URL. Or does AngularJS provide some kind of way to make sure this is prevented?

Comment: Did the answer below address your question?

Answer (score 2):

There is **no way** that you will be able to prevent a technically savvy person from crafting a URL query params, faking a browser or a mobile client, or otherwise making a request with fraudulent data to your server. You can make it harder on them, but not impossible.

Browsers and other client-side devices are at the control of the user, with the notable exception of technologies like DRM.

Treat anything coming from the client as potentially altered.

Instead of having the client app submit points, it should only submit certain actions that the user does, but the score or the points should be tracked and calculated on the server.